# Which sentence sounds more natural?

Tags: expressions

- It takes 10 minutes to complete execution.
- It takes 10 minutes to execute.

Which one is correct or sounds more natural to native speakers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of them are grammatically correct.

The bottom one "10 minutes to execute" is more natural-sounding.

Comment: Thank you, friend. I'll accept the answer in 8 minutes.